# What is the value of electromagnetic coupling at the energy where it merges into electroweak couplings?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, symmetry-breaking, interactions, electroweak

It is  known that its zero-energy value is the fine-structure constant α, about  1/137.036.
Various sources state that the running value is in the 1/129-1/127 range at the Z-boson energy (91 GeV). What should be the value at the electroweak symmetry breaking scale?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the v.e.v. of the SM is about a quarter of a TeV, but that hardly matters, since the EM coupling varies very slowly there,
[image]

So you wish to study the results of [OPAL 2006](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ex/0610037), namely
[image]